# RMS Amplitudes of voltage

Tags: signal-analysis, amplitude, random-process

I am looking here at the course of current fluctuations and have calculated the RMS values, but somehow it seems strange to me: with the black line there are small fluctuations, but the RMS value is still comparably large with, for example, the blue...
The RMS values are:
red:0.83mV
blue:0.44
green:0.52
black: 0.31mV

compare with the picute
[image]

Comment: Root mean square is just the... Root of the mean square of the sample. Dynamics like "the black squiggles less than the blue" don't play a role. Why do you think they should?

Answer (score 1):

RMS includes the mean. If you want a metric for "variation" use the standard deviation instead or subtract the mean first (which is basically the same thing).

For the black curves moves slowly, but it still moves by a good amount. If you want a metric of the "fuzziness" than you can apply a high pass filter first that gets rid of the slow "drift" movemenent.